# Can you use a java library in a Dart application?

Tags: dart

I started working through the Dart tutorials this week and have been pretty impressed with the language, tools, and capabilities. However, I'm still learning the language.

I'm considering writing a server-side application with Dart and would like to import an existing java library and leverage its classes and methods. Is this possible?

I haven't seen any references or samples indicating that this is a valid use case.

Your thoughts and answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Dart and Java are different languages that both run in their own VM.

You can however invoke java via the [Process](https://api.dart.dev/main/dart-io/Process/run.html) class.

There is also a [Java to Dart plugin](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn/trunk/dart/editor/util/plugins/com.google.dart.java2dart) that is in an experimental phase.

Comment: links to nothing ‍♂️